# WSO2AM JWT is duplicated

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We configure APIM to pass X-JWT-Assertion, but every request is duplicating JWT, one with **X-JWT-Assertion** and other with only **assertion**.

Ex.:

**X-JWT-Assertion:** eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0=.eyJp...

**assertion:** eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0=.eyJp..

Is this currectly or a bug?

The problem is, the header size increase a lot in some cases, and some servers block the requests.

Environment:
APIM 1.9.1
Java: 1.7_80
Linux RedHat 6.8

Thank you.

Comment: it should not behave like that.. current version is wso2am 2.1.0 and I don't see extra header sent to the backend..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4082).
You can remove this additional header by editing the '< WSO2AM_HOME >/repository/resources/api_templates/velocity_template.xml' file.

Remove the following lines in the velocity_template file. It will resolve the issue.

```
## check and set jwt
#if($jwtIsEnabled)
<class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.mediators.TokenPasser"/>
#end
```